# MySQL Connector/J v5.x upgrade: query now returning byte[] instead of String

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, casting

I just updated the JDBC driver for my application from

```
mysql-connector-java-3.1.12-bin.jar
```

to

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar.
```

With the v3.x driver, this kind of a query works:

```
select concat("<a href>", count(sakila.payment.payment_id), "</a>") 
from sakila.payment;
```

But now with the new v5.x driver, the query only works with a cast().

```
select cast(concat("<a href>", count(sakila.payment.payment_id), "</a>")
as char(30)) from sakila.payment;
```

Is there any property in the MySQL database I can change? 
I don't want to change hundreds of queries like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you will have to bite the bullet and update your code. There is a bug report [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27551) that seems to match your circumstances and the status of that bug report is "Won't fix". The response from the developers ([4 Apr 2007 17:43] Reggie Burnett) was:

> This is something that we can't really fix.  Let me explain.
>
> MySQL has several issues when it comes to reporting whether a result if binary or not.  This was *very* bad on MySQL versions prior to 5.0 but it's still a problem even today.  The SQL you reported is returned by MySQL as binary when it obviously is not.  The connector can't know for sure.  With 5.0.5 and 5.0.6, we tried to make a "best guess" but that code caused more problems than it solved, so with 5.0.7 we have rolled it out.    Your SQL will return string properly with 5.0.7, but that doesn't mean it's fixed.  In fact, it returns string because we are ignoring the binary flag so that means you could generate valid SQL that should return binary and 5.0.7 will return string.
>
> Until the server is fixed, the connector just can't *always* do the right thing.  I hope this has cleared it up somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Now i can quit my search.